# DropBox syncing all folders, again?

Tags: macos, imac, dropbox

After HDD failure I replaced my iMac HDD and restored Time Machine backup.
Now dropbox likes to resync all of my files, nearly 1 million of them!

Is it normal?

Comment: How would it check without transferring all the data anyway?

Comment: By using something like a hashcode or md5 or ... @Mark

Comment: You can write two different files with the same hashcode etc

Comment: So the question is more of a *Is this normal?* rather than a *why is this happening?* ?

Comment: yes @Thecafremo, I'll edit it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue has come up in the [Dropbox forum](https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=102411#post-554120) as well, with the following answer from support:

> Pause Dropbox, copy the content over. This will cause indexing and the client might even say uploading, but we're not duplicating files in the cloud. Your resync will happen much faster than a re-upload. Just make sure the folder structure remains identical.

If you did a restore from TM, you should already be past the "copy the content over" step and might just see the indexing/uploading step (which shouldn't upload).

Comment: Great, but how can I make sure it's not uploading and using my bandwidth?

Comment: As far as I understand this, it shouldn't upload everything again (even if says so in the menu/status). If your network is busy nevertheless it might be best to follow-up on the issue through the link in the answer.

Comment: @AVEbrahimi To see if the machine is uploading anything, open /Applications/Utilities/Activity Monitor and look at the Network tab.  Or [iStat menus](http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) is another possibility.

Comment: While Dropbox reindexes, disk read access is up at max, and network traffic is unspectacularly. This indicates that Dropbox re-reads all files (heavy disk read load), calculates their checksums, and compares this with the cloud (only very little network traffic). The question is, why it is reindexing. I cloned my HD with SuperDuper, which is doing a very exact clone, just ommiting some caches etc. Either one of Dropbox cache files/dirs was left out, or Dropbox uses inode for UID-ing files as well, and the inodeschanges of course in the clone process. Any input?

Comment: Comments shouldn't be used to ask follow-up question so in general it's better to ask a new question for things like that. As your question is more related with how Dropbox works in general, the Dropbox forum might be the better place to ask.